# Right hand rule: Vector cross product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vectors, conventions

I couldn't figure out the direction of this specific cross product example because of the angle. I tried the right hand rule several times but I can't seem to get it right. How did the direction turn out to be like this? And how should I shape my hand?

[image]

Comment: If you’re having a problem visualizing the right-hand-rule for $\vec{F_1}\times\vec{F_2}$ because you have to put your right hand into an awkward position, try it for $\vec{F_2}\times\vec{F_1}$, which is in the opposite direction. Or use your *left* hand and reverse the result.

Comment: As far as it seems to me that $F_2$ is coming out of the paper (in z-direction) and not in $xy$ plane.

Comment: @Knight Out of the paper but not in the $z$-direction. Look at the indicated angle of 120 degrees with the $x$-axis.

Comment: @G.Smith Well, I meant $zx$ plane but thank you for making it clearer.

Comment: Another version of the right hand rule is to imagine that a spanner (wrench) lies with its handle pointing along the direction of the first vector. Imagine turning it through the smaller angle (120° in this case) to align it with the second vector, supposing that you are using it to turn an ordinary right-handed nut. The direction of $\vec{F_1} \times \vec{F_2}$ is the direction the nut will translate along the screw thread. In this case it is into the page (or screen).

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: AseelMohammad should follow the advice of @BenCrowell as he has given it with full kindness.

Answer (score -1):

I like the following configuration

[image: RHRule]

To get $\vec{a} \times \vec{b}$ make your fingers sweep from one vector to the other, as if you are rotating $\vec{a}$ to meet $\vec{b}$ (dashed arrow below).

The cross product direction is where your thumb points.

In your question specifically, put the base of the fingers at $\vec{F}_1$ and the tips of the fingers at $\vec{F}_2$.

[image: Answer]

Comment: Why the downvote without comment?